# NodeJS http.get with state object in the response

Tags: node.js, http-get

I am struggeling with something that I belive supposed to be quite simple once you know how to do it , I apologize if its already been answered - I have searched throughly and could not find an answer.

In Node JS , I want to perform http.get , in the response parameter, I dont pass a closure but a reference to a function that receive a response in a parameter (that way I can have re usability) but I also want to have a state/data object that will be passed to this response function so I could further handle the transaction - with closures its easy but then I need to copy/paste all the time.

```
 https.get({
        host: 'www.****.com',
        path: ********
    }, this._searchResponseHandler.bind(this));
```

How can that pleased be achieved ?

Thank you ,

James

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind()` to also provide initial arguments to your function (the result of which are called [*partial functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions)):

```
this._searchResponseHandler.bind(this, stateObj)
```

The signature of the handler would become:

```
_searchResponseHandler : function(stateObj, res) { ... }
```